# "Undefined index:" when trying to load .xlsx file using PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel, phpexcelreader

I'm trying to import an .xlsx file into my app. So far it went well with simple files but now I have a complex (formulas, images, charts etc) file and it throws me "Undefined index:" with error in Excel2007.php at line 1501:

```
$objDrawing->setPath("zip://".PHPExcel_Shared_File::realpath($pFilename)."#" . $images[(string) self::array_item($blip->attributes("http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships"), "embed")], false);
```

Any idea what can cause this error?

Comment: http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships Problem loading page?

Comment: @pokeybit Well, that can be a problem. The question is how can I fix it. I put an issue in the PHPExcel repo on Github, hope they can fix it. Meanwhile, i'll try to find what was in that link.

Comment: I had a look but sorry, it's your google time :)

Comment: Something on wiki I believe

Comment: Without a copy of the file that's causing the problem, this is going to be almost impossible to fix..... [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: @MarkBaker well, I am trying to find that file. If I won't find it, I hope the guys from PHPExcel can help me.

Comment: @iceman2hot4u - I __AM__ the guy from PHPExcel

Comment: @MarkBaker Lol. I just read your profile. Sorry. Well, I'll keep searching.

Comment: @MarkBaker do you also need the file that I'm trying to import?

Comment: Generally yes; a working example that demonstrates what's failing.... that line of code is looking for a file included in the xlsx zip, but not actually finding the referenced file

Comment: Unfortunately I can't provide you the file because it's private. I'll try to take it piece by piece and see what causes the problem.